# Error while trying to rename a directory through cmd command from python

Tags: python, cmd, tkinter

I have this piece of python/tkinter code that is trying to rename a directory. When the call() gets executed it trows an error.

```
if os.path.exists(self.destDirectory):
    self.now = datetime.datetime.now()
    print(self.now)
    self.now = str(self.now.strftime("%Y_%m_%d_%H_%M"))
    print('rename {0} {1}'.format(self.destDirectory, 'old_' + self.now))
    self.cmd1 = ('rename {0} {1}'.format(self.destDirectory, 'old_' + self.now))
    self.returnCode1 = call(self.cmd1)
```

ERROR:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback Traceback (most recent call last):  
File "C:\Python32\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1399, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
File "C:\EclipseWorkspaces\csse120\Myproject\src\BoxRestore.py", line 95, in proceed
    self.returnCode1 = call(self.cmd1)
File "C:\Python32\lib\subprocess.py", line 467, in call
    return Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs).wait()
File "C:\Python32\lib\subprocess.py", line 741, in __init__
    restore_signals, start_new_session)
File "C:\Python32\lib\subprocess.py", line 960, in _execute_child
    startupinfo)
WindowsError: [Error 2] The system cannot find the file specified
```

But When I do:

```
print('rename {0} {1}'.format(self.destDirectory, 'old_' + self.now))
```

And execute it in cmd I get no errors.

Another command Won't complain:

```
self.cmd2 = ('xcopy {0} {1} /I /E'.format(self.values['sourceButton'], self.values['destinationButton']))
self.returnCode = call(self.cmd2)
```

Can You Please Help.

Comment: Why would you want to shell out instead of simply using `os.rename`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use this:

```
if os.path.exists(self.destDirectory):
    self.now = datetime.datetime.now()
    print(self.now)
    self.now = str(self.now.strftime("%Y_%m_%d_%H_%M"))
    print('rename {0} {1}'.format(self.destDirectory, 'old_' + self.now))
    os.rename( self.destDirectory, 'old_' + self.now )
```

Comment: +1 for using the built in os.rename() rather than hacky call out to a command prompt.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. One issue,  printing os.rename's paramters I get: C:\Users\lenovo\Desktop\old old_2013_03_27_07_21 
But on running the above call I don't see any old or old_2013_03_27_07_21 on my Desktop. existing old disappears.

Can you tell me why It might be happening?

Comment: `os.rename` can move directories as well as renaming them.  `old_2013_03_27_07_21` is a relative path - it's in whatever directory the script is running in.  If you want to rename the directory to `C:\Users\lenovo\Desktop\old_2013_03_27_07_21`, just pass that as the second parameter to rename.

Comment: Using this, with shell=True:
            self.cmd1 = ('rename {0} {1}'.format(self.destDirectory, 'wsprto_' + self.now))
            self.returnCode1 = call(self.cmd1, shell=True)
Works as expected. But os.rename() doesn't.

Answer (score 2):

There's no "rename" program on Windows.

Instead, "rename" is a built-in command in the command prompt program (`cmd.exe`).  So when you type "rename" at a command prompt, it gets treated specially by `cmd.exe`.

When you run a program using Python's `subprocess` module, then (by default) it doesn't use `cmd.exe`, it tries to run an actual program.  This doesn't work for `rename`.  You can change this by passing the `shell=True` option to `subprocess.call`; if you do that then it should work.  (This also introduces a security vulnerability if you're getting any part of the command line from the Internet or something else you can't trust, which is why it's not the default).

But using `os.rename()` is a **MUCH** better solution - you get better error handling, your program will be faster, more reliable, more secure, simpler, easier for other programmers to understand, and portable to Linux/Mac.  (One example of "more reliable": your current code breaks if the directory name contains a space; but `os.rename()` will just work).

Comment: +1. More permissive `shutil.move()` could be used instead of `os.rename()`